# keep a track of paypal payment made online

Tags: php, paypal

My question may seem to be very basic and view dependent but i wish to know every aspect of it.
I have created a mobile app where the users need to register themselves in order to use the app, but my client wishes to have the admin panel in the form of a website, where the user can  register themselves by paying a specific amount through paypal and then they can use the mobile app version.
I have completed the main page and have created the paypal button on the user page, but for the admin page i wish to show a list of all users who have successfully paid for the product.

Is it possible to do so, can i keep a track of user details and their payments on the website??? if yes then can anyone guide me with it, would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1):

use **Paypal IPN** to save the paypal transaction information to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database. Save each payment record after payment maybe.